# Apache POI has some vulnerability with POI OOXML jar file

Tags: apache-poi

Apache POI has some vulnerability with POI OOXML jar file
Maven Link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/5.2.5

Description: poi-ooxml-5.2.5.jar (latest version) is using  commons-compress-1.25.0.jar which is having 2 vulnerabilities. But we have commons-compress-1.26.1.jar(Latest version) have no Vulnerability. My question to Apache POI is do you have any plan to release new version including commons-compress-1.26.1.jar to avoid vulnerability with common-compress library.

Expecting new release from Apache POI to include commons-compress-1.26.1.jar(Latest version) in their poi-ooxml

Comment: Full details already shared by the project - https://lists.apache.org/thread/97d7g1jjxvp38h4yoqg21v48y8mffsqs